# Java - what data structure should I use?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am writing a Java program which creates sequences and save them.
I'm looking for the most fitted data structure to save the sequences.
I don't know in advance the length of the series, or how many series I will have, and the series can be in different length.

what structure should I use?

Comment: Start with Lists http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Depends what you want to do with series. Do you want to access elements by address? You want fast insert? Fast search? Fast delete? Try with ArrayList and LinkedList first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List` (i.e. `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`) of `Strings` for example. If you want to store more information about the sequence I would recommend to write a class named `Sequence` with a `String` and your additional information in it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to access the items (sequentially or randomly) but an ArrayList or a LinkedList could be a good start.

Here's a discussion of both: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

The data structure basically depends on the type of data you are going to store, and since you are saying that the length is not known in advance, I think you should have a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) in java and then decide which one to use.

Maybe if you provide us a sample data, we might be able to help you better.